# Rails: not a supported controller name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

What is wrong with the way I named my routes?

Do I need to change my folder structure and my module name to

```
:car_registration

/app/controllers/car_registration/steps_controller.rb
```

I would prefer to use the formatting I have, if possible.

### Routes

```
  scope module: 'CarRegistration' do
    resources :steps
  end
```

### Controller

/app/controllers/CarRegistration/steps_controller.rb

```
module CarRegistration
  class StepsController < ApplicationController
    include Wicked::Wizard
    steps :step1, :step2, step3

    def show
      @form_object_model ||= form_object_model_for_step(step)
      render_wizard
    end

    def update
      @form_object_model = form_object_model_for_step(step)
      render_wizard @form_object_model
    end

    private

    def form_object_model_for_step(step)
      "CarRegistration::#{step.camelize}".constantize.new      
    end

  end
end
```

### ERROR

> 'CarRegistration/steps' is not a supported controller name. This can
>   lead to potential routing problems. See
>   http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use
>   (ArgumentError)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have at least two problems. You are using a folder structure like:

```
app/controllers/CarRegistration/steps_controller.rb
```

That is unconventional. Instead, it should be:

```
app/controllers/car_registration/steps_controller.rb
```

Then, your routes should look like:

```
scope module: :car_registration do 
  resources :steps
end
```